# Insert from two tables into one table using procedure

Tags: insert, procedure

I would like to use below Procedure to insert data from Table1 and Table2 into one table using stored procedure. Please give me some hint how can i do it :) I tried to use here union statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertStudent
(
@PlatnosciID VARCHAR(100),
@RoleID VARCHAR(100),
@Imie VARCHAR(100),
@Nazwisko VARCHAR(100),
@Email VARCHAR(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO dbo.Student(PlatnosciID, RoleID, Imie, Nazwisko, Email) 
        SELECT RoleID, @Imie, @Nazwisko, @Email
        FROM dbo.Role
        WHERE RoleID = @RoleID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT PlatnosciID, @Imie, @Nazwisko, @Email
        FROM dbo.Platnosci
        WHERE PlatnosciID = @PlatnosciID
END
GO
```

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

Comment: I think the error message is quite easy to understand. As seen in your code, your SELECT statement contains 4 items (which is `RoleID, @Imie, @Nazwisko, @Email`) but the insert statement above contains 5.

Comment: It's beacuse i have different data in these two columns. Here are the tables(sorry i do not know how to format these code below):
CREATE Table dbo.Student (
[StudentID] int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
[RoleID] INT,
[PlatnosciID] INT,
[Imie] VARCHAR(200),
[Nazwisko] VARCHAR(200),
[Email] NVARCHAR(100)
)
GO

CREATE Table [dbo].[Role] (
[RoleID] int IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY,
[NazwaRoli] VARCHAR(200),
[Status] VARCHAR(200),
)
GO

CREATE Table [dbo].[Platnosci] (
[PlatnosciID] int IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY,
[DataRozpoczecia] VARCHAR(200),
[DataZakonczenia] VARCHAR(200),
[Suma] VARCHAR(100),
)
GO

Comment: Yes? But how could the database understand that and fill `RoleID` and `PlatnosciID` for you? Do you actually want `SELECT RoleID, @PlatnosciID, @Imie, @Nazwisko, @Email` and `SELECT @RoleID, PlatnosciID, @Imie, @Nazwisko, @Email`?

Comment: The main point is to put information in Student Table: PlatnosciID and RoleID. It's about create reference from table Platnosci and Role to Table Student, so when i put insert into Student table i will also have information from platnosciID and RoleID, is my logic is wrong? Can you advise?